# Strange behaviour of MySQL on Windows (CPU 100% with simple query)

Tags: mysql, database, sql, bottleneck

We run MySQL 8 on Windows 2019 server (Dell R420, 32 cores, 64GB, SSDs on Raid10). Every now and then, our website goes completely offline, as the CPU on the MySQL server is completely bottlenecked (CPU 100%).

After a bit of investigation, we found out that these queries pile up and take forever to return results:

```sql
SELECT count(id)
FROM g3hy2_usergroups
```

This is a very simple query. It just returns the number of user groups on that table. That table is InnoDB, and its table size is only 80kB.

When we run this query manually, it takes 0.037 seconds to return the results, but after we run it for (for example) the 40th time, we hit the "bug" and it takes **forever** to return results (it actually runs forever, I suspect until it hits the MySQL timeout).

I don't know if this is a MySQL bug and/or there's something wrong with our database or something else we can't think of.

But we would like for someone with deeper knowledge to give us a hint so we can look in the right direction, and we get one step close to solve this issue.

Btw it's not a hardware issue, as we have tried different servers with the same results.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: On another note, the state of the executing queries that run forever is in the "Executing" state.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE g3hy2_usergroups`.  Also, was anything else running when it took 'forever'?

Comment: Hi @Rick. Thanks for the reply. The result of that query is this: https://justpaste.it/3kv35

Comment: Yes, there are other queries running, many of them. It's possible that another query is problematic and it creates this issue with this simple one?

Comment: In particular, `ALTER TABLE g3hy2_usergroups` could block your very simple query.  Provide the output from `SHOW PROCESSLIST` during the pile-up.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait until this happens again, and I'll post the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST

Comment: hi @Rick. Here's the process list output during bottleneck CPU 100% https://justpaste.it/2yz8t

Comment: @WilsonHauck MySQL it currently uses 48GB of memory out of 55GB allocated to InnoDB

Comment: On this occasion, there's no SELECT count(id) FROM g3hy2_usergroups query, which actually tell us that the problem is not on that query, probably some other queries produce the problem.

Comment: Please show us the entire query that starts `SELECT c.id,c.title, p.* FROM (`, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`.

Comment: Also, if that statement is coming from an `EVENT`, please provide the definition of the `EVENT`.

Comment: Here's that SELECT c.id....query: https://justpaste.it/276at

Comment: @RickJames sorry, what exactly do you mean by EVENT?

Comment: @AlexK. - `|       5 | event_scheduler | localhost            | NULL     | Daemon  | 218063 | Waiting on empty queue     | NULL  ` -- This implies that the "Event Scheduler" is enabled.  (It does say whether you have any `EVENTs`.)

Comment: (`lft`,`rgt`) -- Do you have a hierarchy?  The left-right is a clever trick, but it is terribly slow for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Some composite indexes that will probably help:

```
g3hy2_social_stream_item: INDEX(target_id, context_type, d.created)
g3hy2_social_stream_item: INDEX(target_id, created)
g3hy2_social_stream_item: INDEX(verb, context_type, created, context_id)
g3hy2_content:  INDEX(cat_id, id)
```

This seems to be useless; get rid if it if you can:

```
JOIN  g3hy2_jreviews_content as jc  ON c.id = jc.content
```

Try to move this into the derived table with the `UNION`:

```
    GROUP BY  p.listing_id
    ORDER BY  p.created DESC
    LIMIT  20;
```

That is, try to do the `LIMIT` *before* Joining to `c` and `jc`.  This should decrease the cost of those Joins.

If you succeed in the above task, then move those 3 lines into each `SELECT` of the `UNION`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or

About the stall at 40 copies...  It *may be* that you have 40 copies of this query running simultaneously and they are stumbling over each other -- sharing 32 cores.  My comments above hope to make the query run enough faster to prevent the freeway pileup.

(`EXPLAIN` might help in analysis.)

Comment: Hi Rick, is it possible/allowed to contact you personally?

Comment: @AlexK. - Yes.  mysql at rjweb dot org .

Comment: i have sent you an email

Comment: @AlexK. - spotted in spam folder, tried to move to inbox, lost it.